# What does builtins(internal = TRUE) return?

Tags: r

From [`?builtins`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/builtins):

> `builtins(TRUE)` returns an unsorted list of the names of internal functions, that is those which can be accessed as `.Internal(foo(args ...))` for foo in the list.

I don't understand which functions are being returned.

I thought it would be all the [closure](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) functions in the base package that call [`.Internal()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/Internal).

However, the two sets don't match up.

```
base_objects <- mget(
  ls(baseenv(), all.names = TRUE), 
  envir = baseenv()
)

internals <- names(
  Filter(
    assertive.types::is_internal_function,
    base_objects
  )
)
builtins_true <- builtins(internal = TRUE)
c(
  both = length(intersect(internals, builtins_true)),
  internals_not_builtins_true = length(setdiff(internals, builtins_true)),
  builtins_true_not_internals = length(setdiff(builtins_true, internals))
)
##                        both internals_not_builtins_true builtins_true_not_internals 
##                         288                         125                         226
```

I also thought that it might be the values listed in [`src/main/names.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/56a1b08b7282c5488acb71ee244098f4fd94f7c7/src/main/names.c#L91-L975) in R's source code, and there definitely seems to be some overlap with this, but it isn't exactly this list of values.

What is `builtins()` doing when you pass `internal = TRUE`?

Comment: Waiting to see if you're going to answer this yourself before I start to investigate... ;-)

Comment: One reason for the differences seems to be that if `foo` is returned by `builtins(TRUE)`, it does not mean that there is a function with the name `foo` that calls `.Internal(foo(...))`. For instance, "anyDuplicated" is in `internals_true`, but it does not contain the line `.Internal(anyDuplicated(x, incomparables, fromLast))`. `anyDuplicated.default`, on the other hand does, and accordingly, this function is in `internals` (as defined by you). Whether something similar is true for all the names returned by `builtins(TRUE)`, I don't know.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich This one I need to leave to someone else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stibu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727468/what-does-builtinsinternal-true-return#comment70650007_41727468) is a specific example of the general problem. `?builtins` says that it fetches the names of the objects it returns directly from the symbol table (this is the C symbol table).

And `builtins(TRUE)` returns all the built-in objects callable via `.Internal`. That, however, doesn't mean there must be any function that calls `.Internal(foo(args, ...))` for any `foo`.

Stibu gave one example: the internal function may not be called by an R function with the same name, as is the case for many generic functions where the default method calls `.Internal`.

Another example is something like `.addCondHands` and `.addRestart`, which are called by `withCallingHandlers` and `withRestarts`, respectively.

It's also possible that one R function calls multiple `.Internal` functions. I don't know of an example of that off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 1):

After more digging, it seems that the list of functions is everything in the `R_FunTab[]` object in `src/main/names.c` where the second digit of the `eval` column is `1`.

Here's a script to retrieve them.

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

names.c <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wch/r-source/56a1b08b7282c5488acb71ee244098f4fd94f7c7/src/main/names.c")

fun_tab <- names.c[92:974] %>% 
  stri_replace_all_regex("^\\{", "") %>% 
  stri_replace_all_fixed("{PP", "PP") %>% 
  stri_replace_all_fixed("}},", "") %>% 
  stri_replace_all_fixed("\\t", "")
funs <- read.csv(text = fun_tab, header = FALSE, comment.char = "/")

cols <- names.c[86] %>% 
  stri_sub(4) %>% 
  stri_split_regex("\\t+") %>% 
  extract2(1) %>% 
  stri_trim()
colnames(funs) <- cols

funs$eval <- formatC(funs$eval, width = 3, flag = "0")

# Internal fns have 2nd digit of eval col == 1. See names.c[62:71]
internals <- funs %>% filter_(~ substring(eval, 2, 2) == 1)
```

I see slight differences when examining

```
setdiff(internals$printname, builtins(TRUE))
setdiff(builtins(TRUE), internals$printname)
```

For example `builtins(TRUE)` doesn't include `shell.exec()` if you aren't running Windows; `mem.limits()` was only recently removed from the devel branch of R, so it shows up in `builtins(TRUE)` for the current release version of R.